# Connect two apps remotely using internet

Tags: android

First of all, I am new to Android. I and my friend are trying to develop an app. What we are trying to do is create a chat application but it must also be able to tell the amount of battery left in the other device. Please help me through this. You can also cite examples of codes or URLs to help me with this. If you can explain the process step by step its well and good. Usage of web service is most likely.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? If you have a chat app than it sends and receives strings. You can put all kind of information in strings like 'battery 80%'. So again: what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know about the implementation  details of your chat application .   I can suggest you :

- get the battery remained information (in numbers) from your android device .
- send it to the server . (Here use the web service to fetch the battery information at the right time . )
- From that server you can fetch this information to display inside another device.